# Mysql show rows as null if not exists at the child

Tags: mysql

The result of the query

```
SELECT CFV.VALUE, CF.NAME
FROM CONTACTFIELD CF LEFT JOIN
     CONTACTFIELDVALUE CFV
     ON CF.ID = CFV.FIELDID AND CF.ORID = CFV.ORID
WHERE CFV.CONTACTID = 81 AND CFV.ORID = 976
```

is

```
Value Name
22    fld1 
33    fld2
44    fld3
```

The CONTACTFIELD has 5 rows

fld1
fld2
fld3
fld4
fld5

So I want my query return null if the value not exists eg:

```
Value Name
22    fld1 
33    fld2
44    fld3 
null  fld4 
null  fld5
```

How can I manage this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *second* table need to go in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT CFV.VALUE, CF.NAME
FROM CONTACTFIELD CF LEFT JOIN
     CONTACTFIELDVALUE CFV
     ON CF.ID = CFV.FIELDID AND CF.ORID = CFV.ORID AND
        CFV.CONTACTID = 81 AND CFV.ORID = 976 ;
```

If they go in the `WHERE` clause, then it turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (because `NULL` values fail the condition).

Conditions on the *first* table should go in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This time returns 400 rows(with all rows where CFV.CONTACTID is null). I need only 5 rows

Comment: @user1022786 . . . Perhaps you want an `inner join`.

Comment: I get the solution using the where clause like this SELECT CFV.VALUE, CF.NAME FROM CONTACTFIELD CF LEFT JOIN CONTACTFIELDVALUE CFV ON CF.ID = CFV.FIELDID AND CF.ORID = CFV.ORID AND CFV.CONTACTID = 81 WHERE CF.ORID = 976

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution using the where clause like this

```
SELECT CFV.VALUE, CF.NAME FROM CONTACTFIELD CF LEFT JOIN CONTACTFIELDVALUE CFV ON CF.ID = CFV.FIELDID AND CF.ORID = CFV.ORID AND CFV.CONTACTID = 81 WHERE CF.ORID = 976
```

Thank you  Gordon